# What is the impact (performance wise) on using linq statements like Where, GroupJoin etc on a mobile app in Xamarin Forms

Tags: json, linq, xamarin.forms

Although the question might sound a bit vague and a bit misleading but I will try to explain it.

In Xamarin.Forms, I would like to present a list of products. The data are coming from an api call that delivers json.

The format of the data is as follows: A list of products and a list of sizes for each product. An example is the following:

```
{
    "product": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "P1",
        "imageUrl": "http://www.image.com"
    } 
}

{
    "sizes": [
        {
            "productId": 1,
            "size": "S",
            "price": 10
        },
        {
            "productId": 1,
            "size": "M",
            "price": 12
        }
    ]
}
```

It seems to me that I have 2 options:

The first is to deliver the data from the api call with the above format and transform them into the list that I want to present by using limq GroupJoin command (hence the title of my question)

The second option is to deliver the finalized list as json and just present it in the mobile application without any transformation.

The first option will deliver less amount of data but will use a linq statement to restructure the data and the second option will deliver a larger amount of data but the data will already be structured in the desired way.

Obviously, delivering less amount of data is preferable (first option), but my question is, will the use of a linq GroupJoin command “kill” the performance of the application?

Just for clarification, the list that will be presented in the mobile application will have 2 items and the items will be the following:

p1-size: s – price 10

p2-size: m – price 12

Thanks

Comment: To me the difference is absolutely negligible, in this simple example if you move `sizes` into `product` you will even have a smaller packet...

Answer (score 0):

I've had rather complex sets of linq statements; I think the most lists I was working with was six, with a few thousand items in a couple of those lists, and hundreds or less in the others; to join and where things, and the performance impact is negligible. This was in Xamarin.Forms PCL on Droid/iOS.
(I did manage really bad performance once when I was calling linq on a linq on a linq, rather than calling linq on a list. i.e. I had to ensure I ToList()ed a given linq statement before trying to use it in another join statement;  understandably due to the deferred/lazy execution of linq).